# MYSQL complex Union

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query working so far:

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('theme:', theme_pk) AS global_id,
       theme_name AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS parent_global_id
FROM theme CROSS JOIN program
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name) AS global_id,
       strand_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM strand
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('strand_year:', strand_pk) AS global_id,
       strand.year AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM strand
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('strand_year:', strand_pk, ',unit:', unit_pk) AS global_id,
       CONCAT(unit.unit_code, ' ', unit.unit_name) AS name,
       CONCAT('strand_year:', strand_pk) AS parent_global_id
FROM strand LEFT JOIN unit ON strand.year = unit.year
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h96X8PwQGVG5ZKjBiUhH9w/3)

Table program

```
+------------+--------------+
| program_pk | program_name |
+------------+--------------+
```

Table theme

```
+----------+------------+
| theme_pk | theme_name |
+----------+------------+
```

Table strand

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+------+
| strand_pk | strand_name | theme_fk | year |
+-----------+-------------+----------+------+
```

Table unit

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+------+----------+
| unit_pk | unit_code | unit_name | points | year | theme_fk |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+------+----------+
```

The relationship is:

program -> theme -> strand -> year -> unit

I now need to add to the query the table `learning_event`

Table learning_event

```
+-------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+----------------+
    | learning_event_pk | learning_event_name | unit_fk | strand_fk | core_condition |
    +-------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+----------------+
```

to branch learning events from the parent `unit` to give:

program -> theme -> strand -> year -> unit -> learning event

Note that only learning events related to the strand should show for a given strand and unit.

I have played around with this, but really unsure of how to get this to work with relating learning events to unit and strand.

**UPDATE**

In JSON format, what I have with the existing query is like:

```
{
    "name": "MD",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Professional",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Professional Behavours",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Year 1",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "IMED4443 Integrated Medical Sciences 1"
                }, {
                    "name": "IMED4444 Integrated Medical Sciences 2"
                }]
            }
```

The new output I'm looking for is like:

```
"name": "MD",
"children": [{
        "name": "Professional",
        "children": [{
                "name": "Professional Behavours",
                "children": [{
                        "name": "Year 1",
                        "children": [{
                                "name": "IMED4443 Integrated Medical Sciences 1"
                            }, {
                                "name": "IMED4444 Integrated Medical Sciences 2",
                                "children": [{
                                    "name": "Lecture - CVS"
                                }, {
                                    "name": "Lecture - Type 1 Diabetes"
                                }...
```

and the learning events should only show where this is a relationship with the unit AND the strand.

FYI, the relationships are handled with:

```
$result = $connection->query($query);
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $data[$row->global_id] = $row;
}

$roots = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {   
    if ($row->parent_global_id === null) {
        $roots[]= $row;
    } else {
        $data[$row->parent_global_id]->children[] = $row;
    }
    unset($row->parent_global_id);
    unset($row->global_id);
}

$json = json_encode($roots);
```

**NEW UPDATE**

This query supplied by Jonathan Willcock and modified by me, is close, it shows the Years for all themes and Strands, as well as Units and Learning Events for the the first Theme, 'Professional', but the units are not showing for any other Themes.

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('theme:', theme_pk) AS global_id,
       theme_name AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM theme 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name) AS global_id,
       strand_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM strand
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name) AS global_id,
       strandyear_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM strandyear sy 
INNER JOIN strand s ON s.strand_pk = sy.strand_fk

UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name, ',unit:', unit_name) AS global_id,
       unit_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM unit u 
INNER JOIN strandyear sy ON u.strandyear_fk = sy.strandyear_pk
INNER JOIN strand s ON s.strand_pk = sy.strand_fk

UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name, ',unit:', unit_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('theme:', theme_fk, ',strand:', strand_name, ',strandyear:', strandyear_name, ',unit:', unit_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = le.unit_fk
INNER JOIN strandyear sy ON u.strandyear_fk = sy.strandyear_pk
INNER JOIN strand s ON s.strand_pk = sy.strand_fk
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ZTinUcTYvBuZyuEuKjCq5/1)

Note that the parent_global_id needs to be the same as the preceding global_id.

**LAST UPDATE**

The above query is working fine!  The issue was the unit table.  Update [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ZTinUcTYvBuZyuEuKjCq5/2)

Comment: Are you sure UNION ALL is the right way to build the relationship you described? Hard to tell what you're trying to do since there's no info on the outcome you want. It seems like a join would be more appropriate in your case. If you could share a sample of the expected final output it would be easier to offer some help, since the UNION is putting all of your hierarchy at the very same level and you won't be able to identify what's what afterwards if not applying some sort of logic around your global parent id.

Comment: See updated OP...

Comment: Why does unit have a theme_fk?

Comment: Glad you picked that up...It was put in as a test, it's not being used.

Comment: Eh?  There is no column called `children`.  Show us the output from the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your desired hierarchy is program -> theme -> strand -> year -> unit -> learning_event, then you should adjust your table structure to reflect this.  In particular theme should have a foreign key relationship between theme and program, and you need an extra level for year.  Having a foreign key between theme and program avoids the need for a cross join.  Cross joins have a habit of biting you and are generally to be avoided.

If you look at this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qzEXJfoj68BZuQGNGR8bp1/0) you will see that I have made these changes.  I have called the year level strandyear to avoid using a reserved word, but the intention should be clear.  Now the joins become inner joins (instead of left joins) to pick up the description values from higher levels in the tree, and the bottom level (learning_events) automatically only contains values that match strand, year, and unit, for no other reason than that the structure itself guarantees it, through the simple expedient that each level has a foreign key to the level above.

Note that the foreign keys effectively chain link.  You do not need, for example, a specific foreign key between learning_event and strand, because the intervening keys in the chain guarantee the relationship.

Comment: I can see the logic with this, and the results in your fiddle appear OK, BUT my JSON is not now returning anything after the strands.  It may be something to do with the PHP handling the logic of the results from the query...

Comment: I did delete the relevant tables and recreated with inserts using your SQL fiddle queries... and used your query verbatum

Comment: This is the JSON I am now getting from the altered tables and your new query:  https://130.95.21.120/md/json/data_test.json  Notice nothing after the strands...

Comment: I think what you need to do, is to change the column name from year_name to strandyear_name in the strandyear table.  I have updated the fiddle.

Comment: OK, the array $data shows the years etc after the strands    https://healthed.hms.uwa.edu.au/md/json/generate_array_test.php   However, the PHP that transforms that array to a child parent hierarchy is not showing anything after the strands, see https://healthed.hms.uwa.edu.au/md/json/data_test.json

Comment: I know that the question was around MySQL not PHP, but some advice on this?

Comment: Sorry I haven't used PHP for over 20 years! You might be better off now closing this question and asking a new one about PHP and JSON. I would also suggest recreating the problem with a much smaller JSON extract. It will probably then be easier for the PHP gurus to help you.

Comment: I have just taken another look.  There were some extra spaces in the query, which may have caused the problem with the PHP, since it might have tried to match ' Year 1' instead of 'Year 1'.  I have updated the fiddle.  Worth a try!

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.  The original query produced the correct array structure https://healthed.hms.uwa.edu.au/md/json/generate_array.php

Comment: The modified query as supplied in the answer produces a different array structure https://healthed.hms.uwa.edu.au/md/json/generate_array_test.php

Comment: I think the problem is that the parent_global_id needs to be the same as the preceding global_id as in my OP query, your query changes halfway through...

Comment: Yep, I changed your query to reflect that rule, see UPDATE in OP.  The Years are now showing for all strands, units are showing for the the Professional theme, as are learning events, but no units showing for other themes....

Comment: I have a new question on this worth a bounty of 50 at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57619131/mysql-how-to-modify-complex-inner-join-and-concat-query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `program -> theme -> strand -> year -> unit -> learning event` means that

- A `program` has 1 or more `themes`
- A `theme` has 1 or more `strands`
  etc

Then you need

```
CREATE TABLE program (program_id ...)
CREATE TABLE theme   (theme_id ...,  program_id, ...)
CREATE TABLE strand  (strand_id ..., theme_id, ...)
etc
```

This implements a 1:many relationship between each pair consecutive pair of tables.

A typical one would, in more detail:

```
CREATE TABLE theme (
    theme_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    theme_name VARCHAR(99) NOT NULL,
    program_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- link to the program this theme is in
    PRIMARY KEY(theme_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

(Optionally you could add a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to further emphasize the comment I included.)