# MySQL - How to modify complex inner join and concat query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which works fine, but need to create a version of it which returns only learning events where there is a match on a lookup table `learning_event_presentation_lookup` where `presentation_pk = $presentation` The lookup table contains:

`learning_event_fk` and `presentation_fk`

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('year:', year_pk) AS global_id,
       year_name AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM year 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS global_id,
       unit_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM unit
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS global_id,
       rotation_discipline_block_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM rotation_discipline_block rdb
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = le.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
ORDER BY name
```

I have tried adding the following after the `INNER JOIN`s but get an error "Unknown column 'learning_event_presentation_lookup.learning_event_fk' in 'where clause'" because the table `learning_event_presentation_lookup` is not in the select queries.  But I am unsure of how to add that table in the existing query...

```
WHERE learning_event_presentation_lookup.learning_event_fk = le.learning_event_pk AND learning_event_presentation_lookup.presentation_fk = presentation.presentation_pk
```

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/euDEW1BgYu9KbVDbprkYPP/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a bunch of unions, the rest of the query can be ignored. We only care about this:

```
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = le.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
ORDER BY name
```

We add `learning_event_presentation_lookup` by joining with it on the `learning_event_pk`.

```
INNER JOIN learning_event_presentation_lookup lepl ON lepl.learning_event_fk = le.learning_event_pk
```

And now we can restrict it to only learning events with associated with specific presentations.

```
WHERE lepl.presentation_fk = :presentation_fk
```

Altogether now, searching for only learning events associated with presentation #23.

```
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',rotation_discipline_block:', rotation_discipline_block_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN rotation_discipline_block rdb ON rdb.rotation_discipline_block_pk = le.rotation_discipline_block_fk
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = rdb.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
INNER JOIN learning_event_presentation_lookup lepl ON lepl.learning_event_fk = le.learning_event_pk
WHERE lepl.presentation_fk = 23
ORDER BY name
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x6anEs7fwtK6FdbipyWCai/0)